# ANTRL 4 - no viable alternative at input <EOF>

Tags: antlr4

I have the following main rule in grammar:

```
// main rule
    parse : (statments)+  EOF;
```

I also have these fragments:

```
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;             // Toss out commetns
LINE_COMMENT: ('--'|'#') ~[\n]* -> skip;    // Toss out full line comments
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;               // Toss newlines
WS  :    [ \t]+ -> skip ;                   // Toss out whitespace

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment A : [aA];
fragment B : [bB];
fragment C : [cC];
...
fragment Z : [zZ];
```

I start my parsing:

```
 ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(cqlQuery);
        CqlLexer lexer = new CqlLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CqlParser cqlParser = new CqlParser(tokens);
        cqlParser.removeErrorListeners();
        cqlParser.addErrorListener(new CqlErrorListener());

            ParseTree tree = cqlParser.parse(); 

            ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
            CqlListener listener = new CqlListener(metadata);
            walker.walk(listener, tree);
```

Why do I sometimes get :  ParseException no viable alternative input at ?

Comment: Shouldn't you include `\r` in `LINE_COMMENT `: `LINE_COMMENT: ('--'|'#') ~[\r\n]* -> skip;` If that isn't the issue, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: As Bart already mentioned: Post a grammar and an input that produces the error you experienced.